# Error en gulp " throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event"

Tags: nodejs, gulp

Alguna idea de como resolver este problema.
tengo mi código gulp :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var exorcist = require('exorcist');
var path = require('path');
var mapfile = path.join(__dirname, 'dist/oorden.js.map');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var pump = require('pump');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

//const child = spawn(/^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm', ['run',  service]);
//const child = spawn('npm', ['run', service]);
var jsmin = require('gulp-jsmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', ['concat', 'scripts'], function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    livereload.listen();
});

gulp.task('copiarweb', ['concat', 'scripts2'], function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['scripts2']);
    livereload.listen();
});



//Smash TASK
gulp.task('concat', shell.task([
    './node_modules/smash/smash oorden.all.sources/oorden.all.src.js > dist/oorden.all.js'
]));
```

Al correrlo en la terminal me marca este error

```
root@aposadas-Vostro-3459:/vagrant/html/oorden-js# gulp
[16:33:34] Using gulpfile /vagrant/html/oorden-js/gulpfile.js
[16:33:34] Starting 'concat'...
[16:33:34] Starting 'scripts'...
[16:33:35] Finished 'scripts' after 14 ms
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ./node_modules/smash/smash oorden.all.sources/oorden.all.src.js > dist/oorden.all.js ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Alguna idea

Comment: Hola Akira, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio.Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  sería buena idea indicaras también que tratas de realizar, saludos!

Comment: `oorden.all.sources` está en la raíz del proyecto? Si ejecutas el mismo comando `./node_modules/smash/smash oorden.all.sources/oorden.all.src.js > dist/oorden.all.js` desde la consola funciona bien?

Comment: `oorden.all.source` no es raiz del proyecto,  y efectivamente si ejecuto el comando `./node_modules/smash/smash oorden.all.sources/oorden.all.src.js > dist/oorden.all.js`, desde consola lo ejecuta correctamente

Comment: utilizo la maquina virtual **vagrant** y realizo unos link simbolicos. la raiz de mi proyecto es `/vagrant/html/assets/oorden.all.source/`